# How to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using Spring Security Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a Spring Security version 3.2.3 application that listens to both HTTP and HTTPS. I want any request to the HTTP port to be redirected to HTTPS. How do I configure that using Java only?

[Spring Security javadoc for `HttpSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#requiresChannel%28%29) proposes the following solution (trimmed to the essential):

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.channelSecurity().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

However that doesn't work because `HttpSecurity` doesn't have method `channelSecurity()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replacing `channelSecurity()` with `requiresChannel()` in the code in the question appears to give the desired behaviour. The working code then looks as following:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the above I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error, did you face a similar issue?

Comment: follow this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https