# How to force all my pages in Spring to https protocol

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, http, https

I download the source code of um application and deployed in Heroku, although I can not run it.

Website with the source code: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw5cX.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using Spring Security Java configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650450/how-to-redirect-http-requests-to-https-using-spring-security-java-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web application supports both HTTP and HTTPS. If You want to force all URLs to use HTTPS. All you need to do is to set requires-channel. Spring Security has a simple configuration that allows us to redirect all HTTP-based URLs to HTTPS. All we have to do is to set requires-channel="https" on `<security:intercept-url/>` tag.

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login .../>
    <security:logout .../>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
</security:http>
```

With this configuration, when the user hits http://server/app, it will be redirected to https://server/app.

For more detail have look on [this](http://myshittycode.com/2014/06/12/spring-security-forcing-urls-to-use-https/) link.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so I have to add it to my pom.xml file?

Comment: You are welcome. Define it in spring-config.xml